# Java application calling Anylogic (without export)

Tags: anylogic

I am using AnyLogic University edition (cannot export AnyLogic model). I need my Java application to call an AnyLogic model (passing a few parameters), execute the model and receive the experiment results (from AnyLogic to my application). How can this be achieved?

Another question is, can the same be done from other programming languages (say, VB or Python)? What I mean is, calling an AnyLogic model from Python.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you include some of your code in your question? That will help people answer your question quicker.

Comment: I do not have the code as I do not know if this is a feasible approach. The kind of functionality I need is like those offered by COM/OLE. For example, in Simul8 (another simulation software), it is easy to access the simulation engine through COM interface. https://www.simul8.com/support/help/doku.php?id=features:com

Comment: (cont..) If it is a Java program calling Simul8, then you need a wrapper (JNI) around it, but it works very well. I am trying to find similar functionality for a real-time simulation I am implementing. Basically, my data acquisition software is written in Java/Python, it extracts parameters and idea is to initialise & execute model in Analogic (with results being sent to my program as callback). The main logic will reside in my program.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a ProcessBuilder in Java to execute a shell command, that runs your anylogic model like so (assuming the model is in /c directory on windows):

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c","anylogic 'absolute path to the model .alp file'");
```

There are several ways to then pass back results. The easiest may be to import an Excel file into Anylogic which stores your results, and  then read it with a CSVReadWrite object in your Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your objective behind calling the simulation dynamically using a java application. But one way to do it might be inside Anylogic itself. You can use the 'Custom Experiment' to write any reasonably small java source code and run the model (in iteration if needed) to collect results and possibly even saving the results to a csv file after each run. See the link below for examples and details
https://help.anylogic.com/nav/0_11